# xmlHttp2 function (var params coding needed!)

Tags: javascript

In this page where this code is,there is a form of 3 details
country,gender,topic

So the idea is to send these 3 details to startChat.php and so that the php can extract the 3 details.

The code is as below

```
function startChat()
            {
            xmlHttp2 = GetXmlHttpObject();

            if (xmlHttp2 == null)
                {
                alert("Browser does not support HTTP Request");
                return;
                }

            var url = "startChat.php";
            var params = "country,gender,topic";<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<what coding this should be?????
            xmlHttp2.open("GET", url, true);
            xmlHttp2.send(params);<<<<<<<<is this correct?????
            xmlHttp2.onreadystatechange = stateChanged2;               
            }
```

And also i would need help with the startChat.php part

```
    <?php

include('config.inc.php');
$preference="$_GET[params]";<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<what coding this should be????????????????????????????????????

include('database.inc.php');
mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (inchat,preference) values('N','$preference')");

echo mysql_insert_id();

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

Please help,asking sincerely :(

Answer (score 1):

First off, you ought to use a POST request instead of a GET, because it's clear from your code that this request is supposed to change state on the server.

Your `params` variable should be form encoded. You can do this with `encodeURIComponent`, like so:

```
var params = 'country=' + encodeURIComponent(userCountry) +
             '&gender=' + encodeURIComponent(userGender) +
             '&topic=' + encodeURIComponent(userTopic);
```

Second, you ought to sanitize the data before you insert it into your DB. Otherwise you expose yourself to SQL injection attacks.

<

```
?php

include('config.inc.php');

// need to create db connection before mysql_real_escape_string is called
include('database.inc.php');

$country = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['country'], $con);
$gender = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['gender'], $con);
$topic = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['topic'], $con);

mysql_query("
    INSERT INTO users(inchat, country, gender, topic)
    VALUES('N','$country', '$gender', '$topic')
");

echo mysql_insert_id();

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

Note that I've also changed your DB structure. In general, it's best to avoid putting more than one piece of data into a single field ([DB normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)).

Comment: hi tom,thnx for the answer,but seems like i have another problem,as u see the initial code do not have the var params and send params,so i think it affected the code part where xmlHttp2.onreadystatechange = stateChanged2;               
            }?

Comment: I don't think I understand your new question. It does look like your requesting code will pass the params (although it's not obvious to me where those values will come from). And I explicitly read those values out of the `POST` data in the PHP script. So it looks like the data path is complete from client to server. All you need to do is actually pull those values from the client -- through form fields, prompts, geolocation data, or however you were planning on getting it. That part is pretty easy.

Comment: i have a drop down list to select all those 3 values, and set diff name for them,country,gender,topic,and unlike conventional submit button,i use this code instead to pass on the values to startChat.php and some series of action,the new question is, might there be any changes u suggested that intefere with the xmlHttp2.onreadystatechange function where as i know it is a function to detect successful conduct of previous execution,or if you may please look into the code again..thanks a lot

Comment: encodeURIComponent(userCountry)  refering to this,(userCountry) ,i actually  name the detail exactly "country" so is it really ok this to be filled ur way?

Comment: Ahh. Nope -- it would need to be changed to `country`. I used those names so it would be obvious what the input should be, and I didn't think the values would be global variables. Use your names, and it should work. :-)